# I forgot the door being opened

Tags: gerunds

> I forgot **opening** the door.

When a gerund follows after *forget*, it denotes actual past event, says CGEL. Does the sentence above make any sense at all concerned about the actual past? Or do I have to change it into: *I forgot the door being opened* (= *I forgot to close the door before leaving*), if I want to refer the opening state of the door.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve your construction, one would say, "I forgot *about* opening the door,"
 which would be the participle construction

Another way is, "I forgot *to open* the door," which would be the infinitive construction.

Answer (score 2):

IF you substitute *don't remember* for *forgot* it may illustrate the situation a bit better.

> I don't remember opening the door. (*But it's clearly open, I must have forgot*)

Saying "I forgot *about* opening the door" or "I forgot *to* open the door" means something slightly different and is used more often when opening the door is a step in a procedure that you forgot to execute:

> Why is the door closed? Didn't you follow the directions?  (*I tried to remember all the directions but I forgot about opening the door.*)
>   Note that here the door is closed because you forgot to open it whereas in the first one, the door is open but you forgot that you opened it.